# ReactJS - How can I access the displayName of a component using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building some React components and sometimes would like to log to the console the type of component that's being rendered, by `displayName`, which JSX uses when displaying the name of a component.

From the context of a component, how can I access the `displayName` property?

e.g. how can I make the `console.log` statement in this example show the displayName of the component?

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'HeyHey',

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.displayName);

        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});
```

Intended output in console:

> HeyHey

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's available as the public property `this.constructor.displayName`.

Comment: careful, the constructor is available only when the component is mounted

Comment: What is display name in production (when webpack minimizes scripts). I get "t" instead "MyComponent". How to get name "MyComponent" because I need it like that in my code?

Comment: Update: you can access the name by using `this.constructor.name`.  I am using React 15.4

Comment: component.name works for me, in react 15.5, need to say i pass dumb component to my hoc...

Comment: `this.constructor.name` will return the name of the function and not the React `displayName`. It has nothing to do with React, but is a JavaScript feature, `(function Blah(){}).name === 'Blah'`

Comment: If your `displayName` is not different the the `class` name, and without the component being mounted, you could use: `Component.prototype.constructor.name`.

Comment: `this.constructor.name` works only in development mode, once it's build and packed, it doesn't work anymore for me

Comment: This is very outdated, doesn't work for function components

Answer (score 8):

Below is a full code snippet illustrating in detail how to both get and set the 'name' of both `class` Components and stateless functional Components.

You get a `name` property on a Component *for free*, from name of the `class` Component or the stateless functional Component in code. However be aware that this will be undefined in the case of anonymous classes/functions, and can also be wiped out / changed by code minification.

You *may* define a custom `displayName` property on the `class` Component or stateless functional Component, if you need to customise. This is especially useful for higher order components. It will also always survive minification.

On a `class`, and **here is the part that may not be obvious**, the `name` and `displayName` are properties on the *class itself*. Thats why from *within the Component instance* you have to use `this.constructor.name` / `this.constructor.displayName` and with a *reference to the Component instance* you use `Component.name` / `Component.displayName`. The code below shows this in practice.

Best practice for *using* a Component's name [seems to be](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging):

- Try to use `displayName`
- If that's undefined, try to use `name`
- It that's undefined, fall back to a hardcoded string like `'Component'` / `'Anonymous'`

```js
class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    if (!this.props.wrapped) {
      console.log('ClassComponent')
      console.log(`  displayName: ${this.constructor.displayName}`)   
      console.log(`  name: ${this.constructor.name}\n\n`)
    }
  }
  
  render () { 
    return <div>ClassComponent {this.props.wrapped && '(wrapped)'}</div> 
  }
}

ClassComponent.displayName = 
  'ClassComponentCustom'

const SFComponent = (props) => (
  <div>SFComponent {props.wrapped && '(wrapped)'}</div>
)

SFComponent.displayName =     
  'SFComponentCustom'

const wrap = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount () {
      console.log('HOC')
      console.log(`  displayName: ${this.constructor.displayName}`)   
      console.log(`  name: ${this.constructor.name}`)
      console.log(`  wrapping a Component with:`)
      console.log(`    displayName: ${WrappedComponent.displayName}`)   
      console.log(`    name: ${WrappedComponent.name}\n\n`)
    }
    
    render () {
      return <WrappedComponent wrapped />
    }
  }
  
  // for the wrapped component
  // check for displayName for something more descriptive, 
  // else fall back to name
  const wrappedComponentName = 
    WrappedComponent.displayName ||
    WrappedComponent.name
    
  Wrapper.displayName =
    `WrapperCustom<${wrappedComponentName}>`
    
  return Wrapper
}
  
const WrappedClassComponent = wrap(ClassComponent)
const WrappedSFComponent = wrap(SFComponent)  

const Example = () => (
  <div className="example">
    <ClassComponent />
    <SFComponent />
    <WrappedClassComponent />
    <WrappedSFComponent />
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
.example > div {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: rgb(240,240,240);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: `WrappedComponent.displayName` returns `undefined`, but `name` works well

Comment: @vsync maybe a misunderstanding on my part but I'm not sure what you mean here. Are you talking about the code in my snippet above? If you run it you can see that `WrappedComponent.displayName` is **not** undefined -- it's printed as `'SFComponentCustom'` in the output :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can find it on `this._descriptor.type`

```
Hello <div>{this._descriptor.type.displayName}</div>
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/hutoxuda/2/edit?js,output)

Only use this for testing; it might stop working at any point.  It's unlikely to work in 0.12.

Comment: thanks! btw - how did you find out where it was? Did you know it, or did you search the source or something? I tried jsonifying the component, and searching the source of `react-with-addons`, but didn't see it right off....

Comment: I don't believe it's documented; I just found it on the console.

Comment: @BradParks I just checked and `this.type` is undefined on master, so it likely won't be in 0.11.  I updated it to include something that works in 0.10 and master.

Comment: Interesting - both seem to work to me, but i'll go with `this._descriptoer.type.displayName`, since it sounds more future proof. Thanks!

Comment: @BradParks: *"since it sounds more future proof"* The fact that the property name is prefixed with a `_` means that it's a private property. It may change at any time and is not future proof at all.

Comment: I get that any property that has an _ in it's name is intended to be private - but since the "this.type" way isn't in master - and the private way is, the private way is still more "future proof" - but I get what you're saying ;-)