# DisplayName of export function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read React docs where it was told that by default ReactClass.displayName is defined and = name of class (function).
I have two components. Component A and B and export my named functional component B into another place:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import someImportedclassComponentA from 'otherFile.jsx'

export function B(props) {
      const A = someImportedclassComponentA;
      return (
        <Suspense>
          <A {...props} />
        </Suspense>
      );
    }
```

In the other file (after import B) i want to get **displayName** of B ("B" expected):

```
let name = B.displayName;
```

I get undefined but when i do:

```
let name = B.name;
```

It works and returns "B". It is mean that *function **B*** is recognized as simple function, not React functional component with displayName. How it is possible ? Why it is not react functional component as i expected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS - How can I access the displayName of a component using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708577/reactjs-how-can-i-access-the-displayname-of-a-component-using-javascript)

Comment: The `displayName` was somewhat useful with class based components. But as class based components are de facto obsolete now, I would advice against using displayName for anything. You could assign a displayName to your function component like this: `function B(props){...}; B.displayName = 'MyAwesomeB';` before exporting it.

Comment: @Martin i still don’t understand how to separate in mind function (which name could be given by .name method) and functional react component (which name could be given by .displayName method)

Comment: @Martin react doc don’t separate Class based components and functional according .displayName usage

Comment: React function components are just that: plain old javascript functions, no special type, no magic. And functions do have a `name` property. And you can add your own properties to any javascript function. The React documentation might actually be outdated regarding displayName. They currently work on updating the documentation, see [beta of new docu](https://beta.reactjs.org/).
The displayName property is not automatically filled by React for function components. This is only available for class components.

Comment: @Martin sounds good! Thank you

Comment: @Martin write last comment as answer and i will mark it as right